# Prove that $\int_a^\infty f\ dx$ exists if $f\geq0$, monotone, continuously differentiable, and $\int_a^\infty f(x)\sin(x)\ dx$ absolutely converges

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration, absolute-convergence

This question has been answered [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125113/f-ge0-is-monotone-such-that-int-0-infty-fx-sin-xdx-converges-absolutely).

I see now that holds true because f is monotonous.
$$\int_{(n+1)\pi}^{(n+2)\pi}f(t)dt \le \pi f((n+1)\pi)$$

But why does
$$\int_{(n+1)\pi}^{(n+2)\pi}f(t)dt \le \frac\pi C \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}f(t)|\sin t|dt$$ stand true:

- **The original question:**

During our studies on improper integarls (Calculus II course) we were given the following question:

> Let $f: [a, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a non-negative, monotonous, continously >differentaible function s.t. $\int_a^\infty f(x)\sin(x)\ dx$ absoloutly converges. prove that >$\int_a^\infty f\ dx$ exists.

In a previous question I have shown:

> Let $f: [a, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a non-negative monotonous function s.t. >$\int_a^\infty f(x)\sin(x)\ dx$. Then $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0}$.
>
> - $\int_a^\infty f(t)dt$ converges.

So I do know that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0}$.
The theorem I'm required to prove closely resembles Able's Convergence test for integrals. But it is the other way around. I also tried multiple times with Cauchy Criterion for convergence of integrals by trying a proof by contradiction.

Any elementary analysis by using convergence tests and Riemann integrals will be very helpful!

Comment: It looks like a clear duplicate to me. You should clarify in your question what exactly you do not understand in those answers.

Comment: Thank you! you are correct. I've clarified what I didn't understand in the original answer.

Comment: $f$ is monotone *decreasing* …

Comment: Thank you again. I see now. But I can't seem to figure out why does it imply his next claim. Any idea?